# Failure at finding the value of the dereferenced pointer

Tags: disassembly, address, assembly, pointer

```
000007FEEC55CF58| 48 8D 0D F1 A7 0B 00 | lea rcx,qword ptr ds:[7FEEC617750] | ;7FEEC617750:"500117367"
```

I see the above line in the ollyDBG which has the value of `"500117367"` according to the comment made by the ollyDBG itself.

However, I don't know how to access the dereferenced pointer value. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and go to the `7FEEC617750` memory address, I get an expression like `push rbx` which is not the value shown in the ollyDBG.

I am pretty confused by how I should use the offsets and stack in ollyDBG. *I simply want to know how to access the value of pointer shown in the comment of ollyDBG `[7FEEC617750]` and also find out what accesses and writes to `[7FEEC617750]`.*

**P.S** Thanks to AcidShout for pinpointing, indeed, the debugger is `x64_dbg` the cousin of ollyDBG :)

Comment: There's no dereference happening there. What you see is equivalent to `mov rcx, 0x7FEEC617750`. `lea` does not dereference *even* though the value is inside brackets `[]`

Comment: Also, how are you debugging x64 code inside Olly?

Comment: @AcidShout Indeed it is x64_dbg the cousin of ollyDBG :) sorry about representing the issue in the wrong way I am newbie in reversing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on the disassembly line above in OllyDbg and choose `Follow in Dump`. That will tell OllyDbg to navigate to address `7FEEC617750` in the dump pane and allow you to see the memory at that address:

[image: Follow in Dump]

To see what accesses and writes to the memory at that address, right-click in the dump pane on the first byte of memory at that address and set a hardware breakpoint on-access:

[image: Hardware Breakpoint]

**Edit:**

All that said, AcidShout's two comments above in response to your question are spot-on!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, I am using the x64_dbg, anyway the solution is the same.

Comment: Anyway, whenever I put a breakpoint the program crashes. What should I do in such situation?!

Comment: One question per post. Please create a new post for that new question.

Comment: It is alright but the crashing is related directly to this question?!

Comment: Please check out http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/how-to-access-and-modify-data-segment-when-doing-hardware-breakpoint-crashes-the